# How can I get the Windows uptime in seconds?

Tags: windows-10, batch

The following commands can get the uptime for Windows as a formatted date and time:

```
>wmic path Win32_OperatingSystem get LastBootUpTime | find "."
20201031212925.500000-180

>systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"
System Boot Time:          10/31/2020, 9:29:25 PM

>net statistics workstation | find ":"
Statistics since 10/31/2020 9:29:36 PM

>wmic os get lastbootuptime | find "."
20201031212925.500000-180
```

Given that I would like to avoid:

- Relying on a command not installed by default with Windows 10
- Requiring elevated privileges to run
- Using Powershell
- Using VBScript
- Parsing a formatted date and time string

How can I get the Windows uptime in seconds to use in a batch file?

Comment: Shame that you are avoind powershell. One command would have produced the result: (Get-Uptime).TotalSeconds

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe I'm currently writing out some vbscript to get the uptime which calls `For Each oA in GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System")` and then prints `oA.SystemUptime` - but, as per the question, I'd rather not shell out to VBScript.

Comment: Opposed to this?  powershell -command “(get-uptime).TotalSeconds”

Comment: @Dallas I'd be open to it as a better solution than VBScript if I could guarantee that it would work every single time. I've tried it on two different Windows 10 computers and they both report "ObjectNotFound: (get-uptime:String) [], CommandNotFoundException" - whereas the VBScript version works on both without issue.

Comment: Powershell -command “(new-timespan -start (get-ciminstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).LastBootUpTime -End (get-date)).TotalSeconds” should work.  You can just trim from the decimal onwards.  Hope that helps.

Comment: With rounding...   powershell -command "[math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem).LastBootUpTime -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds)"

Comment: You need Powershell 6 and above to use Get-Uptime

Comment: If you need powershell 6 or above then I’ll need a fallback solution for when it doesn’t work. In which case, I might as well just reduce the complexity by always using the fallback solution. The vbscript might not be pretty, but it has no dependencies.

Comment: To be clear, the last one I gave doesn't require PS 6, and I believe should work going back to PS 3.  I tested on a couple builds of Win 10 and while it isn't quick, it works consistently.  As Señor  mentioned, if you have more than just Windows machines of interest, or if PS is not already on every machine, you may want to consider something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, ***I get why everyone here is pushing powershell***.  ***It's just better*** but doesn't help you if it won't run on OTHER COMPUTERS without installing or updating something.

Instead of using the Windows Scripting Host, use the WMIC tool that comes with windows.  The problem with the WMIC tool is the text it outputs is full of unicode and CR/LF combos making it a pain to parse.  To solve this, we will run whatever WMIC returns through the findstr utility and convert it from "sucks" to "sucks less".

```bat
@echo off

:: Make sure our variable is empty
Set SystemUptime=
Echo SystemUptime="%SystemUptime%"

(for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%v in (
    'wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System get SystemUptime /format:list ^| findstr "[0-9]"'
) do (
    Set "%%v=%%w"
))

Echo SystemUptime="%SystemUptime%"
```

I hope this was what you were asking for.

KEEP IN MIND, ***The WMIC tool is deprecated and will go away eventually***.  Hopefully by then, everyone will have a version of powershell that will work for you.

Comment: Powershell is great but its use as a solution for everything often falls foul of the "*if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail*" adage.

Comment: Yes @Richard, I wrote installers for years.. it was hard to get people to understand that I needed to use a tool that was already in EVERYONE'S toolbox.  Thanks for the check! :)

Answer (score 0):

- EDIT:
  I don't see a clear way around this with batch unless you are willing to download a third party **`Uptime`** utility.

Microsoft released one back in 1999 but has since deprecated it. If you google around a bit you can still find it. (Hint: https://zedt.eu/tech/windows/microsofts-uptime-utility/)

The Microsoft Uptime utility works just fine.

With that utility, and this small script you can get System uptime for the local machine displayed in seconds:

```
@ECHO off

SETLOCAL 

CLS

IF EXIST .\uptime.txt DEL /A /F .\uptime.txt

.\uptime.exe > .\uptime.txt 

FOR /F "TOKENS=6,8,10,12" %%G IN ( .\uptime.txt ) DO (

                            SET /A Days=%%G`

                            SET /A Hours=%%H`

                            SET /A Minutes=%%I

                            SET /A Seconds=%%J

                            )

SET /A TotalUptimeInSeconds=(%Days% * 86400) + (%Hours% * 3600) + (%Minutes% * 60) + %Seconds%

ECHO System Uptime Is %TotalUptimeInSeconds% Seconds.

ENDLOCAL

EXIT /b
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. My laptop has been on for 10 minutes and it's reporting the uptime as always 48 seconds. I suspect you're just displaying the number of seconds past the minute when the laptop was turned on?

Comment: I misunderstood your request.  Your statement that the command `NET STATISTICS WORKSTATION|FIND ":"` returns system uptime is incorrect. That, in turn, lead me down the wrong path in understanding what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Now this may be the worst answer in this question, but anyway an answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
 printf("%lu", time(0));
 return 0;
}
```

Is a C-program that will output the time in seconds since last epoch. Wikipedia page about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions

This sections specifically:

> returns the current time of the system as a time_t value, number of
> seconds, (which is usually time since an epoch, typically the Unix
> epoch). The value of the epoch is operating system dependent; 1900 and
> 1970 are often used. See RFC 868.

But well, do you really want the time in seconds since last epoch? And secondly, if a batch-script is what you are using now: Why not consider a more platform-independent approach? Or mix the "kind of"-solution that I just posted with the batch-scripting? Just compile the C-source statically. When using GNU GCC you do this by adding -static on the commandline or compilation-flags.

Comment: Thanks, however I’m looking for the number of seconds since the computer was turned on (the uptime), not the number of second since the epoch.